# Unexpected token in \android\build.gradle line: 12 : unexpected token: }

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, virtual-reality

I am trying to run a project using react-native.

I followed all the steps given in [Viro's website.](https://docs.viromedia.com/docs/viro-platform-overview)

When trying to build the project using `react-native run-android`, I however get the following error:

```
Could not compile build file '\ARDemo\android\build.gradle'.
```

> startup failed:
> build file '\ARDemo\android\build.gradle': 12: unexpected token: } @ line 12, column 1.
> }
> ^

1 error

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 8s

error Failed to install

```
  // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
} // --> error is detected in this line

allprojects {
    // Workaround for https://issuetracker.google.com/117900475
    // Remove when upgrading to AGP 3.4 or higher
    configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
    config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
        details.useVersion("3.5.0-alpha03-5252756")
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
    }
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
}
```

}

Comment: it looks like you put extra curly bracket or forgot to add

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `repositories {` after `buildscript {`

Try this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories { // --> this was missing
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
} 

allprojects {
    // Workaround for https://issuetracker.google.com/117900475
    // Remove when upgrading to AGP 3.4 or higher
    configurations.matching { it.name == '_internal_aapt2_binary' }.all { config ->
        config.resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            details.useVersion("3.5.0-alpha03-5252756")
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        }
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried this. Didn't help

Comment: So you still get the same error after you added `repositories {` line? Or did it change?